# dlib training a new faces dataset

Tags: python, training-data, dlib

I'm trying to train my set of images with 68 landmarks, and I'm using the train_shape_predictor.py script. The script creates my .dat files but can not locate well the landmarks. The resulting detections are only the rectangle around faces.

I have created the xml file with the landmarks with imglab tool. This looks different from the test file supplied with dlib.

where is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: "This looks different from the test file supplied with dlib." Do you mean structure or data? data will definitely be different for different set of images. You can also try [web](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/imglab) version to label the images, if it helps.